# What do these circled 7's and 8's mean?

Tags: piano, fingering, trills

I'm playing Schubert's 3rd impromptu, op. 90 D899. There is a circled number precisely under each trill, shown below, and I don't know how to interpret them.

[image: The five trills.]

I read [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/35935/piano-sheet-music-curves-on-top-and-numbers-in-circles) that they might indicate a change in the hand's position, but then

- I don't see why the circle notation would be restricted to trills (as the left hand has to do other brusque shifts) and, more importantly,
- it doesn't explain the circled 7 and 8!

Certainly the circled 1, 2 and 5 match the fingering of their respective notes, but how should I interpret the other two numbers? I don't think that they mean intervals as they seem too vague a notation for that purpose and they don't sound right to me.

Any clue on how to play these trills?

Comment: Do they appear in ascending order through the piece? Can you give us any details about what edition you’re reading from?

Answer (score 6):

These circled numbers appear in the [1948 Henle edition](https://imslp.org/wiki/4_Impromptus,_D.899_(Schubert,_Franz)) edited by Walter Gieseking. They appear in numerical order except for no.1 which appears a second time between 6 and 7 (but over an identical measure). They presumably refer to editor's notes by Gieseking (and which are missing in the file on imslp.org).

The numbers are not in the newer [Henle edition](https://www.henle.de/en/Impromptu-G-flat-major-op.-90-no.-3-D-899/HN-488).